# How do I extract information from an incoming JWT that was generated by an external service?

Tags: jwt, spring-security-oauth2, okta

**How do I extract information from an incoming JWT that was generated by an external service? ([Okta](https://www.okta.com/products/api-access-management/))**

I need to perform a database lookup of user information based on one of the fields in the JWT.  (I also want method-level security based on the scope of the JWT.)

The secret seems to be in using an `AccessTokenConverter` to `extractAuthentication()` and then use that to lookup `UserDetails`.  I am stuck because every example I can find includes setting up an Authorization Server, which I don't have, and I can't tell if the `JwtAccessTokenConverter` will work on the Resource Server.

My resource server runs and handles requests, but my custom `JwtAccessTokenConverter` is never getting called during incoming requests; 
All of my requests are coming in with a principal of anonymousUser.

I am using Spring 5.1.1.

My Resource Server Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OauthResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${oauth2.audience}")
    String audience;

    @Value("${oauth2.baseUrl}/v1/keys")
    String jwksUrl;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources
                .tokenServices(tokenServices())
                .resourceId(audience);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() throws Exception {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());

        return tokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwkTokenStore(jwksUrl, accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        return new CustomJwtAccessTokenConverter();
    }
}
```

My Custom Access Token Converter

```
public class CustomJwtAccessTokenConverter extends JwtAccessTokenConverter {

    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
        OAuth2Authentication authentication = super.extractAuthentication(map);
        Authentication userAuthentication = authentication.getUserAuthentication();

        if (userAuthentication != null) {
            LinkedHashMap userDetails = (LinkedHashMap) map.get("userDetails");

            if (userDetails != null) {

                ... Do the database lookup here ...

                Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = userAuthentication.getAuthorities();

                userAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(extendedPrincipal,
                        userAuthentication.getCredentials(), authorities);
            }
        }
        return new OAuth2Authentication(authentication.getOAuth2Request(), userAuthentication);
    }
}
```

And my Resource

```
@GET
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('openid')")
public Response getRecallsByVin(@QueryParam("vin") String vin,
                                @QueryParam("page") Integer pageNumber,
                                @QueryParam("pageSize") Integer pageSize) {
    List<VehicleNhtsaCampaign> nhtsaCampaignList;
    List<OpenRecallsDto> nhtsaCampaignDtoList;
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();


    Object principal = securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

 ... More irrelevant code follows ...
```

First of all, the `@PreAuthorize` annotation isn't doing anything. If I change it to `@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('FooBar')")` it still lets the request in.

Secondly, I need to grab other information off the JWT so I can do a user lookup in my database.  I thought that by adding the `accessTokenConverter()` in the resource server config, the JWT would be parsed and placed into the `securityContext.getAuthentication()` response.  Instead all I'm getting is "anonymousUser".

UPDATE: I later found out the data I need is coming in a custom header, so I don't need to extract anything from the JWT.  I was never able to validate any of the suggested answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spring Boot?

The Spring Security 5.1 has support for JWT access tokens.  For example, you could just supply a new `JwtDecoder`:
https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot/blob/spring-boot-2.1/oauth2/src/main/java/com/okta/spring/boot/oauth/OktaOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfig.java#L62-L84

Comment: I am not using Spring Boot.

Comment: BTW, this is an extension of my previous question (https://devforum.okta.com/t/getting-invalid-jose-header-kid-error/3291), but I felt it has strayed too far from the original problem so I started a new thread here on SO.

Comment: With Spring Security 5+ new OAuth support you need to enable support to process those annotations. IIRC something like:
`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)`

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter that validates and sets token to `SecurityContextHolder`. This is what I have done in my project using `jsonwebtoken` dependency:

```
        public class JWTFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

            private String secretKey = 'yoursecret';

            @Override
            public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
                HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
                String jwt = resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
                if (validateToken(jwt)) {
                    Authentication authentication = getAuthentication(jwt);
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            }

            private String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request){
                String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
                if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                    return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
                }
                return null;
            }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
            Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(secretKey)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =
                Arrays.stream(claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString().split(","))
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            User principal = new User(claims.getSubject(), "", authorities);

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, token, authorities);
        }

public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {      
        }
        return false;
    }
        }
```

You can then access your token from `SecurityContextHolder`.

For cleaner way to access token fields, I have created POJO models of my token from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/